# Error in /etc/nanorc in GIT for Windows, no /usr/share/nano

Tags: nano

I got this error while using nano in Windows Terminal, with GIT-bash.

```
$ nano .bashrc
Error in /etc/nanorc on line 237: Error expanding /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Got my answer [here](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/5796), that I will copy-paste here in case the content is lost:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight
$ cd nano-highlight
$ cp * /usr/share/nano
```

Answer (score 2):

run this command from git bash (as admin)

```
dos2unix /usr/share/nano/git.nanorc
```

It fixes line breaks, which are different in Linux and Windows.

from :
https://www.scivision.dev/git-for-windows-nano-error-fix/